# Scan a directory in my webserver and list all of its images

Tags: php, image, file, filesystems, media

On my webserver under the directory path `sites/default/files/app-images`, I have the below images:

- image-1.png
- image-2.png

I am trying on Cron Run to:

1. Scan this Directory.
2. Check if directory is not empty.
3. Loop through all available images and for each; get its filename.
4. Delete that image.

So far, I did the below:

```
$Directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator('sites/default/files/app-images');
$Iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new \RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.png$/i', \RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
foreach ($Regex as $info) {
  $filename = $Regex->getFilename();
// Display a message    
\Drupal::messenger()->addWarning(t("$filename"));
}
```

1. Is it the best method to use in term of performance ?
2. I am getting the filename of the images with file extension like `image-1.png` and `image-2.png` but how to get the filename without the file extension, Ex: `image-1` and `image-2` ?
3. How to delete the image after getting its name ? I have tried `unlink($filename);` but with no avail, the image still exist in the directory !

Can anyone set me on the right track please ?

Thank you

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: RecursiveDirectoryIterator is what you are looking for. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: Can you please check the update of the question, Thank you